# Deploying environment-dependant configuration to Apache Karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

Is there a standard way of deploying environment-dependant cfg files to karaf? Let's say I have xyz.cfg file in 2 versions for Dev and QA. Do I need to create separate features for Dev and QA in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Afaik, it's not possible. A cfg file can have system properties and default value, but I don't  think it's possible to choose a feature based on a system property

Comment: Do you mean deploy to running Karaf? If so, how do you deploy the cfg file? Script? CI?

Or do you mean, you need to assemble different versions of the application for different env?

Comment: Please find my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a way with features. But I don't know how. We use the `karaf-maven-plugin` to build a customized karaf. In this case you may build one for Dev and one for QA. [Here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/karaf/site/production/manual/latest/karaf-maven-plugin.html) is a full description.

So hopefully this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution for what I am looking for. 
Karaf features support the provisioning of configuration files. See "Features configurations" and "Feature configuration files" section here:

https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/provisioning

All I had to do is to add a feature for each environment where I include only the configuration files required for that environment. Then for the deployment, I deploy both my bundles and the feature containing the configuration for the environment I am trying to deploy to.

Example:

```
<feature name="dev">
  <configfile ...>
</feature>

<feature name="qa">
  <configfile ...>
</feature>
```

Then, to install in dev:

```
repo-add my-repo

feature:install some-feature-containing-bundles

feature:install dev
```

Comment: This isn't good because you have to have different artifacts and distributables for different environments, rather than promoting the same artifact up through environments.

Comment: The bundles are the same for all the environments, but the cfg's are naturally different. So, the idea I am describing above is to have 1 repo having 1 feature which contains the bundles, and 1 feature for each environment which contains the cfg's for that specific environment. Then, when promoting to a specific environment, install the bundles features first then install the feature containing the cfg's for the target environment.